# Is there a reason that my table cells won't toggle onclick?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make *Conway's game of life* in codepen with pure JavaScript and DOM. I need to toggle the style and `value` attr of the each cell `onclick`. I can't quite get this to work so here I am.

js/dom:

```
//HTML:
var tbl = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
const size = { x: 5, y: 5 };

for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
    tbl.insertRow(i);
    tbl.rows[i].style.height = "49px";
    for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
        tbl.rows[i].appendChild(document.createElement("td")); //Add the cell
        //Style cell
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.width = "49px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.padding = "0px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.border = "solid 1px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].setAttribute("value", "false"); //Add value
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (!this.getAttribute("value")) {
                this.setAttribute("value", "true");
                this.style.background = "black";
            } else {
                this.setAttribute("value", "false");
                this.style.background = "white";
            }
        });
    }
}

//CSS:
document.body.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.position = "absolute";
document.body.style.left = "0";
document.body.style.right = "0";
document.body.style.top = "0";
document.body.style.bottom = "0";
document.body.style.margin = "auto";
tbl.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.border = "solid 1px";
tbl.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";

//JS:
function step() {
    for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
            //Put Conway's rules here
            if (!tbl.rows[i].children[j].getAttribute("value")) {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
            } else {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "black";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the help of @Heretic Monkey I can now toggle the cells but only once:

```
var tbl = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
const size = { x: 5, y: 5 };

for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
    tbl.insertRow(i);
    tbl.rows[i].style.height = "49px";
    for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
        tbl.rows[i].appendChild(document.createElement("td")); //Add the cell
        //Style cell
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.width = "49px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.padding = "0px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.border = "solid 1px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].setAttribute("dada-value", "false"); //Add value
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (!this.getAttribute("data-value")) {
                this.setAttribute("data-value", "true");
                this.style.background = "black";
            } else {
                this.setAttribute("data-value", "false");
                this.style.background = "white";
            }
        });
    }
}

//CSS:
document.body.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.position = "absolute";
document.body.style.left = "0";
document.body.style.right = "0";
document.body.style.top = "0";
document.body.style.bottom = "0";
document.body.style.margin = "auto";
tbl.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.border = "solid 1px";
tbl.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";

//JS:
function step() {
    for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
            //Put Conway's rules here
            if (!tbl.rows[i].children[j].getAttribute("data-value")) {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
            } else {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "black";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `insertRow()` returns the `row` element created, so you could use that instead of repeating `tbl.rows[i]` 10 times... Also, you can use `insertCell()` to add the `td` element, which likewise returns the element, eliminating the need for `children[j]`. Move your `style`s into CSS classes and use `classList` to add/toggle them, and you'll find the amount of code is reduced by 90%...

Comment: As for the reason it won't work... `td` elements don't have a `value` attribute; use `data-value` and the `dataset` interface to get/set the value.

Comment: Im not using real css as a self imposed challenge.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Using data-value half fixed the problem, I can toggle the elements but only once. _If the element starts out white I can make them black then white but not back to black._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `console.log(typeof (this.getAttribute("value")) )` in the function, it will show  `string` rather than `boolean`.

I have replace your code

`if (!this.getAttribute("value"))`

with this:

`if (this.getAttribute("value") == "false")`

and I think it works like what you want..

```js
    //HTML:
var tbl = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
const size = { x: 5, y: 5 };

for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
    tbl.insertRow(i);
    tbl.rows[i].style.height = "49px";
    for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
        tbl.rows[i].appendChild(document.createElement("td")); //Add the cell
        //Style cell
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.width = "49px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.padding = "0px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.border = "solid 1px";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].setAttribute("value", "false"); //Add value
        tbl.rows[i].children[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.getAttribute("value") == "false") {
                this.setAttribute("value", "true");
                this.style.background = "black";
            } else {
                this.setAttribute("value", "false");
                this.style.background = "white";
            }
        });
    }
}

//CSS:
document.body.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
document.body.style.position = "absolute";
document.body.style.left = "0";
document.body.style.right = "0";
document.body.style.top = "0";
document.body.style.bottom = "0";
document.body.style.margin = "auto";
tbl.style.width = size.x * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.height = size.y * 50 + "px";
tbl.style.border = "solid 1px";
tbl.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";

//JS:
function step() {
    for (var i = 0; i < size.y; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size.x; j++) {
            //Put Conway's rules here
            if (!tbl.rows[i].children[j].getAttribute("value")) {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "white";
            } else {
                tbl.rows[i].children[j].style.background = "black";
            }
        }
    }
}
```